# How to connect a /dev USB modem in an LXC container?

Tags: lxc, modem, dev

I've been struggling with [various](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545359/lxc-usb-device-passthrough) [tutorials](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137931/usb-passthrough-for-lxc-containers) to hook up my `/dev/ttyACM0` in a lxc container.

Basically I've tried adding the following line in my lxc config :

```
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = c 166:* rwm
```

And the following one too (both with relative and full path) :

```
lxc.mount.entry = /dev/ttyACM0  dev/ttyACM0  none  bind,optional
```

but yet, I can't get a working configuration.

FYI on the host side the modem is working and my host shows up :

```
$ ll /dev/ttyACM0
crw-rw---T 1 root dialup 166, 0 janv. 29 16:47 /dev/ttyACM0
```

Comment: In the mount entry, you need to specify the full path, aren't you? `lxc.mount.entry = /dev/ttyACM0  /path/to/your/container/rootfs/dev/ttyACM0  none  bind,optional`

Comment: hi @EduardoRamos, yes, as said, I've tried both relative and full / absolute path

Comment: Yes, you are right. I read wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a modem, but I tested with my pendrive to connect it direct with the container.

My device on the host:

```
    brw-rw---- 1 root plugdev 8, 16 Jan 29 15:17 /dev/sdb
```

My container config:

```
    ...
    lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = b 8:16 rwm
    lxc.mount.entry = /dev/sdb /var/lib/lxc/multi2/rootfs/dev/sdb none bind 0 0
```

But when try to start it, I got the following error:

```
    ERROR    lxc_conf - No such file or directory - failed to mount '/dev/sdb' on '/var/lib/rootfs-lxc//dev/sdb'
```

Then I tried to create the device file in the container /dev:

```
    sudo touch /var/lib/lxc/multi2/rootfs/dev/sdb
```

When I tried start it again, it worked! In the container console:

```
    root@multi2:~# ls -l /dev/sdb 
    brw-rw---- 1 root plugdev 8, 16 Jan 29 15:17 /dev/sdb
    root@multi2:~#  fdisk -l /dev/sdb

    Disk /dev/sdb: 1000 MB, 1000341504 bytes
    251 heads, 2 sectors/track, 3892 cylinders, total 1953792 sectors
    Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disk identifier: 0x784ffaa9

       Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
    /dev/sdb1            2048     1943551      970752    b  W95 FAT32
```

Everything as expected.

Comment: It Works! Nice! I'll take some time later today to be sure but I think it was due to the fact that I was told do do a `mkdir` where you did a `touch` (and didn't think about it)

Comment: @Eduardo Ramos - I'm trying to do this on unprivileged container (lxc 2.0.7) but I can't get past the error that you mention